# Named Function in Node.Js to avoid Callback hell not working

Tags: node.js, callback

I am trying to resolve the callback hell using the named function technique, but the callbacks are not working properly. Rather an error stands `TypeError: callback is not a function`.**I am providing the code below and giving in-line comments to show the erroneous lines**.

```
function displayWorks(works) {

    console.log(`Username: ${works.user} has [${works.work}] works`);
}

function getWorks(user) {
    console.log("User", user);
    getWorks(user, displayWorks);
}

console.log("Before");
getUser(1, getWorks);
console.log("After");

function getUser(id, callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Reading users from Database");
        callback({id: id, gitHubUserName: 'John Doe'}) // callback not working
    }, 2000);
}

function getRepositories(username, callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Reading HowToWork.Com API");
        var works = {userName: username, works: ['work1', 'work2', 'work3']};
        callback(works); // not working
    }, 2000);
}
```

**Edit 1:** I am using NodeJs version v6.14.3. Is this a problem for version.

Comment: The problem is solved. The function `getWorks(user)` has a call to `getWorks(user, displayWorks)` which means that there is an overloaded `getWorks()` method. Sadly, Javascript does not have such concept as method overloading. Here, changing the method names a bit did the work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You call callWorks inside callWorks. Maybe you want to call getRepositories instead

2) You call the callUser providing the callback the wrong way.

voilà

```
function displayWorks(works) {

    console.log(`Username: ${works.user} has [${works.work}] works`);
}

function getWorks(user) {
    console.log("User", user);
    getRepositories(user.gitHubUserName, (works)=>{
        console.log(works)
    })
}

console.log("Before");
getUser(1, (user)=>{
    getWorks(user)
});
console.log("After");

function getUser(id, callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Reading users from Database");
        callback({id: id, gitHubUserName: 'John Doe'}) // callback working
    }, 2000);
}

function getRepositories(username, callback) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Reading HowToWork.Com API");
        var works = {userName: username, works: ['work1', 'work2', 'work3']};
        callback(works); // working
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a correct approach. But somewhere I read that the anonymous function call is not needed in order to invoke the method. Have a look [here](https://stackabuse.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-node-js/) -> Read from sub-heading **Declare your functions beforehand**. Can you please look into the matter.

Comment: You can safely revert `getUser(1, (user)=>{getWorks(user)})` to `getUser(1, getWorks)` and it will still work perfectly

Comment: @slebtman It's not working. The problem I faced was there were two methods `getWorks()` with the same name but different parameter count, and I think there the problem lies.

Comment: @gkont As your answer is one of the ways that serve the purpose I accepted it as an answer. Keep answering.